# grouping list object by attribute using java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have data like this:

```
[
   {
      "category":"Fruits",
      "name":"Apple"
   },
   {
      "category":"Fruits",
      "name":"Manggo"
   },
   {
      "category":"Vegetables",
      "name":"Water Spinach"
   }
]
```

I want to grouping by java 8, I've tried with :

```
Map<String, List<MyData>> myData
    = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getCategory()));
```

But the result is not what I need. Because the result I expected was `Fruits = 2, Vegetables = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the result you're after, you'll need to use a [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector together with a [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) collector:

```
Map<String, Long> soldCopiesStats = list
    .stream() 
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyData::getCategory, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collectors.counting` as the downstream collector of `groupingBy` to get the count in each group.

```
Map<String, Long> myData = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.getCategory(), Collectors.counting()));
```